# how to show in jenkins a multi select list option with a single choice list beside each multi-select list value?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

in my jenkins job if i enter a ticket number My jenkins job  should go to jira and  get a list of values. these values should show as a multiselect list option in jenkins. for each value in multiselect list option there should be a editable select list option beside to the each value of the multi-select list option.for example  if i have 5multi-select list values there should be 5 select list fields beside each value of the multi-select list option.so for each value of multiselect option there should be editable select field. is it possible? please help me out. i heard by exteded choice plugin i saw the documentation but i am not understanding how to configure it. please help me out.

Comment: Hi rick, what have you tried so far?